# SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal when attempting to insert variable inside of path

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am attempting to have a Discord bot re-add all items from existing lists upon reinitialization, such that the titles of each list are saved in a preexisting local `.txt` file (e.g. `AAA_filenames.txt`), with items separated by semicolons (which the code successfully detects as individual parameters). Each title parameter is saved as another `.txt` file, and its items are appended to that file, once again, separating themselves by semicolons such that it can be read.

To my knowledge, all of this is completely successful and works perfectly, but the only problem I have is that I can't seem to put a template literal inside of a path (see paragraph 4 for an example path).

I've tried many things, most of which I've forgotten, but I can tell you that I've tried everything that both made sense to me and was on StackOverflow (to my knowledge).

Since I am using `Discord Bot Maker` (along with `DBM-Mods`) as my tool to format my code due to its efficiency and overall ease, I will be reluctant to release that code due to the fact that very few legitimate Discord bot creators use it (to my knowledge, of course), so for now, I will give you an example of the path that just doesn't work:

```
.\TXTSTORAGE\${tempVars("param-x")}.txt\
```

While I am aware that I am not supposed to simply post one line or an entire file, the startup initiative event is very long and its functions are spread throughout the entire file, so... my hands are tied here. Instead, I will tell you that *all variables are stored correctly.*

I've had the bot send back messages to the console and to a private `Discord` channel confirming that all variables do indeed exist and their values match up perfectly with what they should be.

I've also had the path point directly to the name of an existing `.txt` file that works the same way as the others in the same directory, that's all well and good, but it stops at one point because not all of the variables are in play when I do that; it must point at the variable-dubbed `.txt` file, which is fully dependent on which parameter `AAA_filenames.txt` has selected. So, that does confirm that the path itself can be read - however, it will refuse to read from a template literal, despite every other command on `Discord Bot Maker` allowing full access to template literals in this context.

I fear that it may have something to do with the raw code involved, but I couldn't find any issues with it. Maybe I've been working for too long at a time... but here's the raw text:

```
# ... rest of code
 {
      "filename": "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Sans Undertale\\Undewtale\\TXTSTORAGE\\${tempVars(\"param-x\")}.txt\\",
      "storage": "1",
      "varName2": "file-x",
      "name": "Read File"
    },
# ... rest of code
```

My expectations are listed in the first paragraph... actual results listed in title. Function refuses to read from path and carries on throughout the function until it's failed too many consecutive times. **So, here's what I'm looking for:

1. A vastly simpler way to force lists and their items to persist throughout resets without changing variable names
   OR
2. A solution to this simple-looking, but quite possibly impossible issue.

My only condition: `Discord Bot Maker`-compatible, or at least compatible with a `Node.js`-exclusive export of the bot.**

Comment: To use template literals you'll have to wrap the path in backticks (\`) instead of double quotes ("). So your path string would look something like: `\`C:\\User...${tempVars(\"param-x\")}.txt\\\``

Comment: Tried that, got the exact same error message. In the setup that I have, backticks are completely unnecessary in order to carry out template literals; they're automatically interpreted with or without backticks. I ended up finding a completely different method of doing this involving a few more files, but many more variables, and a highly efficient method of variable storage. Thank you!